# Cloud spanner: Read write transaction retries to be off

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I'm require to switch off the retries in readWriteTransaction query block. Can anyone please help me out?

Our application is in Java (Spring boot), I have tried this using the retry settings while creating the DB client but that doesn't work out for me.

I have tried the code something like this -

```
    import com.google.cloud.spanner.Spanner;
    import com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerOptions;
    import com.google.cloud.spanner.DatabaseClient;
    import com.google.cloud.spanner.DatabaseId;
    import com.google.api.gax.retrying.RetrySettings;
    import org.threeten.bp.Duration;

    //My Bean/Class Definition code here

    // Customize RetrySettings to switch off retries.
    RetrySettings retrySettings = RetrySettings.newBuilder()
        .setMaxAttempts(1) // This ensures no retries.
        .build();

    // Create SpannerOptions with the custom RetrySettings.
    SpannerOptions options = SpannerOptions.newBuilder()
        .getSpannerStubSettingsBuilder()
        .executeSqlSettings()
        .setRetrySettings(retrySettings)
        .build();

    // Create a Spanner service object.
    Spanner spanner = options.getService();

    // Get the DatabaseClient.
    DatabaseId db = DatabaseId.of("my-project-id", "my-instance-id", "my-database-id");
    DatabaseClient dbClient = spanner.getDatabaseClient(db);

    // Use the DatabaseClient to run a readWriteTransaction.
    dbClient.readWriteTransaction().run(transaction -> {
      // My transaction logic here.
      return null;
    });
```

But still the retry is not being switched off somehow. Can anyone please help?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind elaborating a bit on **why** you want to disable retries, and **what type** of retry it is that you want to disable?

It's not entirely clear what type of retry that you want to disable. There are two things that could be retried in the Cloud Spanner client library:

1. A single RPC invocation, for example a single invocation of `ExecuteSql`. For that, your configuration is in principle correct. **However**, the Java client library uses the `ExecuteStreamingSql` RPC to execute **queries**, and the `ExecuteSql` RPC to execute DML statements (insert/update/delete statements). Your configuration will therefore only prevent retries of DML statements.
2. You specifically mention 'switch off the retries in readWriteTransaction query block'. This might indicate that you want to switch off retries of read/write transactions. Cloud Spanner can abort any read/write transaction for various reasons, and the client library will retry the read/write transaction if it is aborted by Cloud Spanner. This happens automatically when you use a `TransactionRunner` as in the given example. If you really want to disable retries of read/write transactions, then you can use a `TransactionManager` instead (see https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/078b7ca95548ac984c79d29197032b3f813abbcf/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/DatabaseClient.java#L459). Note however that this option is intended for advanced use cases, for example for implementing your own driver.

Comment: Actually I want to disable the retries in readWriteTransaction block, because in my application I am seeing a concurrency issue where 2 threads are changing a value of a record which we want to be changed only once. And if first thread has changed and committed the transaction then other one must be failed and it must not be overridden. Hence we want to disable the retries in this block. Hope this answers your doubt.

Comment: In that case, I would say that you should fix that problem in a different way. If you want to fix that problem by disabling transaction retries, you end up with:
1. Depending on the transaction actually being aborted to prevent the second update. That will only happen if the transactions happen to be executed in parallel. If they are executed by two parallel threads, there's always also the chance that they are executed serially.
2. Cloud Spanner can abort a read/write transactions for multiple reasons. You would then also disable retries for all other cases.

Comment: Instead of disabling retries, you should make sure that only one of the threads actually start the update process and/or only one of the threads is started in the first place.